# I would like to add a function that allows the customer to add multiples of the same product to their basket, how can I do this easily?

Tags: plugins, e-commerce

We have recently had our website redesigned but it has left us with some issues. The developers didn't add any function in the add to basket stage or checkout stage for the customer to choose to add more than 1 of the same product. Is there a way of adding this ourselves at the Wordpress backend which isn't too complicated? I have tried adding plugins but can't seem to find one for this specific issue and the one that seems like it would be ideal hasn't worked.

We just want a simple drop down menu for each product to choose the quantity and we would also like to be able to put this function in the basket stage as well.

Comment: What plugin are you using for ecommerce? Or is it custom?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention - It's WooCommerce

Comment: WooCommerce already lets you add multiples of a product to the cart. On the product and basket page there should be a quantity field. Double check that your products don't have the "sold individually" option selected in the back-end.

Comment: https://kofc.co.uk/product/murano-glass-clear-crystal-globe-medium/ I have unchecked the "sold individually" option in the back end but it hasn't changed anything. Do you think it's the web design itself overriding the function?

Comment: If you press Add Basket twice it says “You can add a maximum of 1 Murano glass clear crystal globe medium's to your cart. You already have 1.”. This is not the default behaviour. You have a plugin or setting configured to add this limit. If you remove it then the quantity field should appear. Contact your developers for help if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Unfortunately it's not really an option to talk to the people who designed the website any more. I'll have a further look into it and see if I can find whats blocking the function. Thanks.